# How do I take advantage of batching when trying to access pool3 activations in the pre-trained inception3 model

Tags: tensorflow

I can currently do the following:

```
 pool3 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
 pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': data})
```

where data is the binary stream of a single image

```
data = gfile.FastGFile(img_name, 'rb').read()
```

Instead of passing each image stream individually, can I stack them up? What if the images are all of different sizes? How does the op graph deal with images of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DecodeJpeg can only load a single image at a time. You can see some examples of applying resize_bilinear operations to an image after it's been loaded here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L621

Once you've resized multiple images to matching dimensions, you can expand them to 4D using expand_dims, and then concat them together along the batch dimension to get a batch.

Comment: Pete,

I tried this and received the following error when feeding it to 'ResizeBilinear:0'

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (19, 299, 299, 3) for Tensor u'ResizeBilinear:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'

Will I need to tweak the graph to make it accept a batch of size greater than 1?

A longer description of the error is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977551/error-while-trying-to-feed-a-batch-of-images-to-inception