# Error while trying to feed a batch of images to inception

Tags: tensorflow

I get the following error when I create and try to feed a batch of resized images to the pretrained inception model.

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (19, 299, 299, 3) for Tensor
>   u'ResizeBilinear:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'

According this this ticket https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1021 inception-v3 model should now take batches. I installed the latest version of tensorflow using pip, but that didn't seem to help. What am I doing wrong?

Update: Here's what I am trying to do:

Hi. Not sure what you mean by original code/data. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{'ResizeBilinear:0': data})
```

where data is obtained as follows:

*each image is reshaped to [1,299,299,3]*

```
resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(decoded_image_4d,
                                              incept_shape_as_int)
```

and then concatenated together as follows:

```
data=sess.run(tf.concat(0,concat_images,name='batch_input'))
```

This does seem like an issue with the graph being older, but I don't see how I can update that.

Stack trace:

```
File "/home/s/Code/Vis/inception_local.py", line 222, in extract_features_batch
    pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,feed_dict={'ResizeBilinear:0': data})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 625, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (19, 299, 299, 3) for Tensor u'ResizeBilinear:0', which has shape '(1, 299, 299, 3)'
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the original code/data? What is the command did you use to run the code?

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by original code/data. Here's what I am trying to do:

pool3_features = sess.run(pool3,{'ResizeBilinear:0': data})

where data is obtained as follows:

#each image is reshaped to [1,299,299,3]
resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(decoded_image_4d,
                                              incept_shape_as_int)

and then concatenated together as follows:

data=sess.run(tf.concat(0,concat_images,name='batch_input'))

Comment: Hi, how did you get concat_images from resized_image? Which line introduced error? Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Concatenation works fine, used tf.concat

The error is clearly a result of the 'ResizeBilinear:0' expecting a tensor of batch size 1

Updating original question with stack trace